# Sum values of properties inside array of custom objects using reduce

Tags: swift

I have following model

```
class Foo {
var value: Double
var color: UIColor

init?(value: Double, color: UIColor) {
    self.value = value
    self.color = color
  }
}
```

How can I sum all `value` property inside of `[Foo]` using reduce?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It simply like this

```
let sum = array.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }
```

Answer (score 9):

The same way as with plain numbers:

```
let foos: [Foo] = ...
let sum = foos.lazy.map { $0.value }.reduce(0, +)
```