# Swift - How to add struct attributes in an array?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to make a checkout screen for an ordering app. I made a struct called dish which has the price as a property. I want to display the total, but I don't know how to total up the prices. I've attempted to use `cart.reduce(0, +)`, but it gives me the error "Ambiguous reference to member '+'".

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Struct and struct array:

```swift
//My struct
struct Dish {
    var price: Double
}

//Struct array
var cart: [Dish] = []
```

Adding to cart:

```swift
//Add an item to cart
    @IBAction func DishTwoOrdered(_ sender: Any) {
        cart.append(Dish(price: 7.50))
        checkoutQuantity.text = "In your cart: \(cart.count)"
    }
```

Adding indices:

```swift
@IBAction func ringUp(_ sender: Any) {
        //Error here
        let sum = cart.reduce(0, +)
        sumLabel.text = "Total: \(sum)"
    }
```

Comment: Do not show photos of code!

Comment: `let sum = cart.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.price }` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49046981/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use this in 95 line

```
let sum = cart.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.price }
```

Comment: I think your answer is better than just closing this as a duplicate. The duplicate question implies that the answer is "just use reduce" but the answer is **really** "use reduce and provide an expression that adds the current sum with the specific field of your struct."

Comment: @DuncanC Yes but his answer was incorrect and he changed after seeing my comment. Anyway I think we can find a better duplicate to add there like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/43911758/2303865

Comment: Personally I prefer to use map and then reduce, like `let sum = cart.map {$0.price}.reduce(0, +)` since it lets your reduce statement simplify to `(initial_value, operator)`, but that's personal taste.

Comment: @DuncanC you can use `map(\.price)` in Swift 5.2 or using the extension from my answer `sum(\.price)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't see an edit on his answer. How did he change it without leaving an edit entry?

Comment: @DuncanC It was before 5 minutes. His original answer was `let sum = cart.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }`

Comment: @LeoDabus I keep forgetting about the keypath form for things like that. I need to train myself to start using it. My employer is a big enterprise and our tool-chain tends to lag behind the latest and greatest, so I am sometimes slow to pick up the "new shiny."

Comment: @DuncanC You can use the custom method from my answer on earlier versions of Swift AFAIR. If it doesn't work you can use the version I had before my last edit. `extension Sequence {` `func sum<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(_ keyPath: KeyPath<Element, T>) -> T { reduce(.zero) { $0 + $1[keyPath: keyPath] } }` `}`